# How to solve the potential performance issue for child component

Tags: ember.js

I have create an multi-selectable table which allows you to select multiple rows; however, in order to check the current marking (whether checked OR not) I need to do the following.

Inside the `table` component,

```
  {{#each rows as |row index|}}
    {{table-x-row
      row=row
      index=index
      data=data
      selected=(mut selected)
      maxSelectionCount=maxSelectionCount
    }}
  {{/each}}
```

Inside the `table-row` JavaScript file,

```
  classNameBindings: ['isSelected:selected'],

  isSelected: computed('selected.[]', {
    get() {
      const index = this.get('index');
      const row = this.get('data.rows')[index];
      return this.get('selected').includes(row);
    }
  }),
```

Code above triggers every time the selected list changes plus for every `table-row` components which means if I have **10** rows. The computed property will get called for **10** times.

Any suggestion to solve this performance issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to simulate the case you have mentioned in the following  [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/823a25166e48a3ab91c0917189b0dc9d?openFiles=templates.components.table-x.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.table-x-row.hbs) by simplifying the table and row (they are not actual table and rows; but just dummy components to illustrate the case). The computed property within `table-x-row` is being calculated for every row as you mentioned. This is problematic both in terms of performance and data encapsulation. Passing all the `selected` array of `table-x` to every row breaks data encapsulation. Why does individual rows need to know about selection state of other rows (I mean `selected` attribute of the table)?

In order to avoid that you can crate a computed array property in `table-x` and pass `isSelected` information directly to the rows like in the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/9a92c68f8cdef45d58df8d33b169d3d7?openFiles=components.table-x.js%2Ctemplates.components.table-x-row.hbs). By this way; the computed property `rowsWithSelectionInfo` defined in `table-x` is only modified when actual `rows` change; and nothing is recalculated when a row selection changes. Each individual row is now passed its `isSelected` property individually and hence does not know about whole data or whole selection info of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need few mins to read your sample.

Comment: @LiXinyang sure; I will be happy to help further if anything is not clear.

Comment: No problem; by the way you can check ember addon [ember-contextual-table](https://github.com/tubitak-bilgem-yte/ember-contextual-table) for an extensible ember table.